# API services vs application logic?

Tags: php, api, codeigniter

I am creating user tracking and reporting module for my social website in codeignitor and wanted to know to create the business logic is it better to code in as part of the codeignitor framework in php or use API services to move data? In which case will you use which?

Answer (score 0):

An API is generally, an interface which allows other services to utilize/modify data.

An actual website itself and an API are two different components, both of which you could use any number of frameworks to develop (including codeigniter).

When you say 'move data', where is this data coming from? Are you referring to using Google Analytics data?

You need to be a bit more specific in your question.

Comment: No, move data between tables and databases. The reporting tables are on a seperate database from the logging tables. So when users undertake an activity, the activity info is logged to the logging table. Then a corn job is scheduled to copy it to a temp table along with other table data to denormalize the data. Then it is copied to a feed table for the feeds. At the same time the denormalized data is copied to temp tables in another database then loaded into the reporting tables. Currently all of this is within the codeignitor framework. So i am thinking maybe have web services to move these?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that your business logic be in separate class(es). The business logic may access API of services if necessary and if so should be accessed through an instance of the Database class.
The data from the browser is to me moved to the business objects created from the aforementioned classes. The Session class should help you manage issues like the session termination.
I hope that codeignitor does it for you. An alternative would be Zend which may be more mature.
Good luck